# Convert UNIXTIMESTAMP to date using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

I am getting date in the form of unixtimestamp

ex: 1321367459.0  (Equivalent to Tue, 15 Nov 2011 14:30:59)

I want to convert the time stamp to date format using javascript

using jquery also no problem

Comment: Answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date(1321367459.0 * 1000);
```

Comment: What's with the '.0' part? You don't need that in JavaScript.

Comment: @kzh, sorry, just copied it from the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a Date object using : `var d = new Date(milliseconds);`.